# Yii - scopes applied after beforeFind in relation

Tags: php, sql, yii, scopes, yii-events

I created a test scope that adds some test condition to DB criteria and applied it in `X::model()->with('Y:test')->findByPk(1)` By dumping DB criteria in beforeFind I can see the condition is not added there, however by logging the sql query I can see that the condition is added to the whole query which basically means that the scope is applied but after beforeFind (tried in relation as in the example above). This makes no logical sense. How can I fix this? My version of Yii is 1.1.14.